# Launch chromedriver from Source Control Explorer location

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to reference and launch chromedriver.exe from a location within Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio. I've saved the chromedriver.exe into a folder called Utilities within Source Control explorer and checked it into TFS. I am not sure of the correct way to go about this.

It makes more sense for chromedriver to get accessed from a checked in location if anyone else was to check out the project on another machine.

I tried the following below and a few other variations.

```
  public IWebDriver StartDriver()
    {
        _driver = new ChromeDriver(@"$/E2E Test Automation/Admin Portal/Utilities");
        return _driver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In C# we can fetch the current Directory of executing application using

```
using System.IO;
String Path=Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
```

and from here u can navigate to path where the Chrome Driver is saved. This should work all machines no matter where the files are synced.

I hope this helps